# Where to post enhancement/feature requests

Tags: support

Recently I posted a question.
Which was closed as off topic.

I then thought. Hey, now I don't know where to post my question.
I don't even know where to ask where to post my question.

I then came up with enhancement/feature ideas to help with this situation.
So I wrote a feature request, which I was about to post on meta, here.

I then realised that... feature requests may not be allowed on meta.
Are feature requests allowed on meta? This could be a question on meta-meta.

I can't bring myself to suggest opening a meta-meta for super-user (Actually, I'm sure the geniuses at S.E. thought a solution to this).

Sadly, I'm afraid this question is a duplicate. Rationally, this question is off topic anyways.

I feel anxious.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feature requests are [on-topic for Meta Super User](https://superuser.com/help/whats-meta).

> What is "meta"? How does it work?
>
> Meta is for...
>
> ...Super User users to communicate with Stack Exchange the company
> (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or **proposing new features**)

You may get better response on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), particularly if it pertains to the entire Stack Exchange system, but is not a necessity to post there.

Answer (score 1):

Feature enhancements? [Meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)